# Avoid using two nested for loops in order to increase performance

Tags: python, performance, dataframe

I'm trying to replace all the elements in a dataFrame in a particular column through some other elements which are stored in a dictionary.
The dataFrame I have is schematically built like :

```
dict_main = {'Elektro':[1,2,3],
             'Nucleo':[88,22,23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_test)
```

and the dictionary where I want to get the elements from is basically

```
dict_elements = {'1': 'ABC',
                 '2': 'CDE',
                 '3': 'EFG'}
```

What I tried is to use two for loops to replace the elements in the 'Elektro' column where they match the keys of dict_elements. The code looks like:

```
for index in df.index:
    for key in dict_elements.key():
        if df.loc[index]['Elektro'] == key:
            df.loc[index]['Elektro'] = dict_elements[key]
```

But as you can imagine if you have several thousand elements in the dataFrame and the dictionary this will take a lot of time... how can I improve the performance. Or is there a better and faster alternative to my approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can use built-in pandas function to accomplish this task --

```
dict_main = {'Elektro':[1,2,3],
             'Nucleo':[88,22,23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_main)
```

and the dictionary where you want to get the elements from:

```
dict_elements = {1: 'ABC',
                 2: 'CDE',
                 3: 'EFG'}
```

I edited your dict_elements to have int instead of str for the keys and this can become a one-line with built in pandas function

```
df['Elektro'].replace(dict_elements,inplace=True)

  Elektro  Nucleo
0     ABC      88
1     CDE      22
2     EFG      23
```

One thing to note is that values that do not match a key in the dictionary will remain as-is in the original dataframe. You can use a map function instead to have them appear as NAs if you'd rather have that behavior. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MarkusGrimm glad I could help. Would you mind accepting this as the answer?

Comment: Yes, definitely!